# Use SessionFactory in Hibernate5 and Springboot 2.1.x

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am migration my Spring boot 1.5.x app to Springboot 2.1.x, We use spring-data-jpa for our crud operations. For inserting blob object i was using following code:

```
@Bean 
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf) {
        return hemf.getSessionFactory();
    }
```

```
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
```

```
    private FileContent getContent(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        FileContent fileContent = new FileContent();
        LobCreator blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(getSession());
        fileContent.setContent(blob.createBlob(file.getInputStream(), -1));
        return fileContent;
    }
```

In Hibernate 5 HibernateEntityManagerFactory is deprecated and existing solution is not working after migration following exception is thrown:

```
Field fileContentRepository in com.example.demo.api.RestController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
```

Looks like entityManagerFactory bean is not created.

Comment: If you use springboot, you don't need to care about the `SessionFactory`. Remove it. And please update the controller and repository to see what happens

Comment: Problem is creating blob object, As lob creater takes in session object.

Comment: @Sam where is LobCreator part in this article?

Comment: @JunaidAkhtarBhutta sory mate. posted in the wrong thread